# ruby FTP passive mode error

Tags: ruby, ftp

I have tried to use FTP with passive mode:

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp =  Net::FTP.new
ftp.passive = true
ftp.connect('mydomain.com')
ftp.login
filenames = ftp.nlst
```

But have got error:

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)
```

Though **with active mode it works fine**!

I use ruby 1.9.3. When I set debuge mode:

```
ftp.debug_mode = true
```

I see:

```
 **ftp.connect('mydomain.com')**
connect: mydomain.com, 21
get: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
get: 220-You are user number 3 of 50 allowed.
get: 220-Local time is now 11:43. Server port: 21.
get: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
get: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
=> nil
irb(main):103:0> ftp.login
put: USER anonymous
get: 230 Anonymous user logged in
put: TYPE I
get: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
=> true
irb(main):104:0> filenames = ftp.nlst
put: TYPE A
get: 200 TYPE is now ASCII
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (1,27,13,19,17,15)
put: TYPE I
get: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)
```

Also I have found out, that in function `transfercmd` from `Net::FTP` host is used, different from my domain ip address! Maybe it is a private ip address? What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure your server allows passive mode? Looks like the ports are closed

Comment: Have you checked weather your server provides the ability to connect passive mode ?

Comment: Yes, my server provides the ability to connect passive mode. I have checked using FTP client.

Answer (score 9):

I have overwritten method [`makepasv`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/FTP/makepasv) from `Net::FTP` and it works!

```
module Net
  class FTP
    def makepasv # :nodoc:
      if @sock.peeraddr[0] == "AF_INET"
        #host, port = parse227(sendcmd("PASV")) #WAS!
        host, port = parse229(sendcmd("EPSV"))
      else
        host, port = parse229(sendcmd("EPSV"))
      end
      return host, port
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice work, that did the trick, there is a patch fix there somewhere!